# can't access to rstudio server with my remote computer

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I have installed rstudio server on WSL on my host computer.
When i try to access to the rstudio server with my another computer, the access is being denied.
I can access to the server with my host computer either using "http://localhost:8787" or "http://[ip address]:8787", but why can I not access to it with my client device with "http://[ip address]:8787"?

The host computer is connnected to the network in my office and the client is connected to my mobile phone network. Is this perhaps the reason? I thought I would be able to work in exactly the same environment from any device anywhere with rstudio server. But, now I can just use it only with my host computer, which is not really different from using Rstudio desktop app on it.

Host computer:

- Windows10
- WSL2 (Ubuntu)

Client computer:

- Windows11

Comment: How is access to your office network from outside configured? Can your client computer access that network at all? (E.g., at work I need to use VPN to connect to our RStudio Server installation when working remotely. We don't just want to open our network to the internet, after all.)

Comment: @Roland, Thanks for your comment. I can only access to the office network with LAN. I have to use the remote secured service that my company specified. Did you build VPN by yourself? or your company provided? I am not quite familier with network stuff, so perhups my question is out of the point.

Comment: Talk to your company's IT/network admin. If you can only access the network via LAN then you obviously cannot access your RStudio Server installation via a mobile network connection.